# posting from iphone app to twitter and facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, twitter

I am posting from my iphone app to both FB and twitter using the below code

**But how can i post directly without showing a composer**

```
 -(IBAction)fbposting{

   if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook ]) {


    slComplose = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [slComplose addImage:imageV.image];
    [slComplose addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://newagesmb.com"]];

    [slComplose setInitialText:self.textView.text];
    [self presentViewController:slComplose animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

[self.textView resignFirstResponder];

}

```
-(IBAction)twitposting{
   if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter ]) {


    slComplose = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [slComplose setInitialText:self.textView.text];
    [slComplose addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://newagesmb.com"]];

    [slComplose addImage:imageV.image];

    [self presentViewController:slComplose animated:YES completion:nil];

   }
   [self.textView resignFirstResponder];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following method in SLRequest class to get a Request object

```
+(SLRequest *)requestForServiceType:(NSString *)serviceType requestMethod:(SLRequestMethod)requestMethod URL:(NSURL *)url parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

then post the request

```
performRequestWithHandler
```

Comment: how to use that...?

Please give me a correct idea with my above code